# How do I check if an application is installed?

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-xe5

How do I check is a specific application is installed on Android 4.x? If it's installed, I want to launch it from my application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use next code:

```
uses
  FMX.Helpers.Android, Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText;


function IsAppInstalled(const AAppName: string): Boolean;
var
  PackageManager: JPackageManager;
begin
  PackageManager := SharedActivity.getPackageManager;
  try
    PackageManager.getPackageInfo(StringToJString(AAppName), TJPackageManager.JavaClass.GET_ACTIVITIES);
    Result := True;
  except
    on Ex: Exception do
      Result := False;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
   Label1.Text :=  BoolToStr(IsAppInstalled('com.embarcadero.Project12'), True);
end;
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I use this if it helps since version 2.1

```java
public boolean checkHasFull(){
    try{
        Context foreignContext = createPackageContext("packagename", Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY | Context.CONTEXT_INCLUDE_CODE);
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        Class<?> yourClass = foreignContext.getClassLoader().loadClass("packagename.mainclassname");    
        return true;            
    }catch(Exception e){ }
    return false;
}
```